# Nothing with a z value greater than 1 is rendering in OpenGL (Pyglet)

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I am trying to learn some basic OpenGL using Python, and i keep having issues.

Nothing with a z value that is larger than 1 will render correctly. If every vertex has a z greater than 1, the whole polygon doesn't render, and if only some of them are greater than 1, then it cuts the polygon wherever it passes z=1. I have tried setting my far clipping plane using `gluperspective()` and `glfrustum()` and neither seems to do the trick.

Edit:  I have tried putting print statements in both `on_draw` and `on_resize`, and yes they are both called

Here is my code:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=1000, height=600, resizable=True)


@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(65, width / float(height), .1, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    #return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED   <Saw on a tutorial, but nothing renders if enabled

@window.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(400, 400, 10)
    glVertex3f(200, 400, 1)
    glVertex3f(200, 200, 1)
    glVertex3f(400, 200, 0)

    glEnd()


glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
pyglet.app.run()
```

And this is what it prints out:

[image]

I've tried so many different things that I don't know what else to try. What is the problem here?

Comment: Make sure that `on_resize` is called. I'm not sure if pygames will call it when starting up.

Comment: also make sure that `on_draw` called. The screenshot does actually not really match the result I would expect if `on_resize` was never called, but it also does not match my expectations if `on_resize` was called.

Comment: @derhass I've tried putting print statements in both, and they are both called

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Im not using pygames, im using Pyglet, and on_resize is called as soon as the window is created

Comment: @nife552 My bad, that was a typo.

Comment: @nife552: there must be more to this. What other gl functions do you call in your program? I don't know pyglet in detail, how is the buffer swapping handled there?

Comment: @nife552: another thing that bothers me is the "<Saw on a tutorial, but nothing renders if enabled" part: you actually should see nothing after that perspective is set up, since your quad will be _behind_ your "camera".

Comment: @derhass that is the whole program, I run small programs when I'm trying to find the source of a problem.  And i've tried setting the quad z to positive and negative

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem try using `pyglet.graphics` instead of interacting straight with OpenGL, I don't know why, but that solved it.  And if you still don't see anything, try putting the z value to a larger negative z value. I tried -200 and it showed up.

```
pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v3f',
                                  (40, 40, -200,
                                   20, 40, -200,
                                   20, 20, -200,
                                   40, 20, -200)))
```